# Is it possible to declare and initialise an unordered_map as a function argument?

Tags: c++

One can declare and initialize an unordered map in a single line like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> colors({{"sky","blue"}});
```

But is it possible to do it in place of a function argument ?

For example, if I have a function with the following signature:

```
void foo(std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> inputColors);
```

Can I call it by declaring and initialising the map as the argument some how ?

Eg:

```
foo(std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> colors({{"sky","blue"}});
```

EDIT: What is the correct way to do it ? Provide the syntax with example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just provide an initializer:

```
foo({{"sky", "blue"}});
```

That will be used to construct a temporary `unordered_map`, which will be passed to the function. If the function is overloaded such that there is an ambiguity, then you can spell the name out fully.

```
foo(std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>{{"sky","blue"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  program will create a `rvalue` reference for that parameter.

```
void foo(std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> colors)
{
    for(auto &x : colors)
    {
       std::cout<< x.first<<"\n";
       std::cout<<x.second<<"\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
  foo({{"sky","blue"}});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax ? Example - how to do it?